# Replacement of .live() on Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

again. Well,I'm doing also pushState script i was doing it with jquery 1.6.2 but it was working with .live() but with v2.0.3 of jquery it's deprecated. So, I don't know how can I replace it, look:

```
$('.a').live('click', function(e){
        history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
        replacePag(this.href);
        e.preventDefault();
        $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
        replacePag(location.pathname);
    });
    });
```

When i run it with one element with class .a it works fine, but my page has many .a elements. I tried it with .on() but neither it doesn't works.

```
$('.a').on('click', function(e){
            history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
            replacePag(this.href);
            e.preventDefault();
            $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
            replacePag(location.pathname);
        });
        });
```

If you can help me, Thanks for your help.

Well, my script is:

```
$(function(){
    var replacePag = function(ur) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ur,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(dat){
                var domm = $(dat);
                var titl = domm.filter('title').text();
                var htm = domm.filter('#body').html();
                $("#body").fadeOut(100,
                function(){
                    $(this).html(htm);
                    $('title').text(titl);
                    }).fadeIn( 1000 );
            }
        });
    }

    $('.a').live('click', function(e){
        history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
        replacePag(this.href);
        e.preventDefault();
        $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
        replacePag(location.pathname);
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, you can't just replace `.live` with `.on` word for word, you have to target a currently existing element. Check zeh docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on function allows you to get round this by handling them on another element when the event "bubbles up to" a parent element. In this instance, we could say the document element – there may be a more specific common parent you could choose.

try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.a', function(e){
    history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
    replacePag(this.href);
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
        replacePag(location.pathname);
    });
 });
```

Comment: perfect, accept the answer if you have solved your problem @Darkness

Comment: I have two answers that says the same xD

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.a', function(e){
    history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
    replacePag(this.href);
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
        replacePag(location.pathname);
    });
});
```

you need to bind to document to pick up the new elements as they're added.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mmm, no it didn't work. I tried it too.

Comment: Apologies, I saw it as `a` elements, not classes of `.a`, try the updated code :)

Comment: yes, i tried changing a to .a